# What is the difference between these two notifyproperty methods?

Tags: c#

Is one better than the other? Are there any notifyproperty that is best practice?

Method 1:

```
 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Method 2:

```
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

I'm mainly confused about the "([CallerMemberName] " in the second method, I'm not sure what it does, I think it add an empty string to calls without a string/null, so should I mainly use the second one as it has more broad use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an optional `string` parameter is marked `[CallerMemberName]`, the compiler provides the calling member's name. So:

```
public string Foo {
    get { ... }
    set { ...; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

automatically provides the `"Foo"`, saving you some minor inconvenience of explicitly specifying the member name.

Comment: So it doesn't matter at all which one you use, it¨'s just a matter of preference?

Comment: @JsonDork well, if I used the first version, then the code I've shown wouldn't compile... but if I had used `OnPropertyChanged("Foo");` or `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Foo));` then yes indeed it would be entirely down to preference - but the preference is: do you like this *convenience* feature

Comment: I see, wouldn't it be better than to use the first one that wouldn't compile? Because don't you Always want them to have the proper string entered into?

Comment: @JsonDork and if I use the second version and do nothing: they always *are* correct; the compiler isn't going to get the name of the caller wrong, but **I might**, especially if I rename something

Comment: Ah, I see. Now I understand it, it's a matter of preference but the second one is the superior coding practice. Thanks a lot Marc!

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

> You can use the `CallerMemberName` attribute to avoid specifying the member name as a `String` argument to the called method. By using this technique, you avoid the problem that **Rename Refactoring** doesn't change the `String` values. This is especially useful for the following tasks:
>
> - Using tracing and diagnostic routines.
> - Implementing the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface when binding data. This interface allows the property of an object to notify a bound control that the property has changed, so that the control can display the updated information. Without the `CallerMemberName` attribute, you must specify the property name as a literal.